# display plain text page in android

Tags: android, plaintext

I want to display a text page in android app, which is having description about my app. This text page will be displayed after clicking upon a button. I have several buttons and I want to display various pages for every button. Could you help me ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `TextView`?

Comment: Why don't you use a TextView to show the description?

Comment: Create new `Activity` as many as your buttons then use `Intent` to redirect to other activity and per activity create a `textView` for the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:-

Create one layout in which you show your desired buttons.
Set setOnClickListener on Buttons.

Second:-

Create different Layouts for every button click Page results.
Like you have 5 buttons then create 5 Layout containing TextViews.

Third:-

set Intent call on every Button.
Put this code on every Button click Intent calling method.

```
Intent intent= new Intent(Firstactivity.this,secondactivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I created up to this. I struck at secondactivity.class

Comment: I searching how to create secondactivity.class . to display a bunch of lines. I am new to android. Kindly help me to get out of this issue.

Comment: For every layout (XML)  you have to create a Class(.java), in which you have to declare everything like Layout Containing textView, imageView etc. So that will be your second Activity.

Comment: This is the simplest example for intent call: http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-intent-example/

Comment: thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge. :)

Comment: no problem bro. keep it up

Comment: @rahul try to follow questionnaire structure provided by stackoverflow to get rid of down vote to your question.